# style.border error in angular4

Tags: css, angular

I'm working with angular 4 and when I use this:

```
<pre [style.border="color_seleccionado=='red' ? '5px solid black' :'1px solid white'"]>
```

I have the following error:

```
 EmpleadoComponent.html:6 ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '[style.border' is not a valid attribute name
```

I have imported this: 
    import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
    import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

And I have done it on app.modules.ts and It doesn't work, why?. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brackets should be properly placed.
It should be like this...

```
[style.border]="color_seleccionado=='red' ? '5px solid black' :'1px solid white'"
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of using it is

`<pre [style.border]="color_seleccionado=='red' ? '5px solid black' :'1px solid white'">`,

where you must have added `this.color_seleccionado = 'red'` inside your component.

Also, it is better to use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) to add styles to your component.

Comment: On the component I have this:  this.color_seleccionado='#ccc';

Comment: Sry, I missed what you are trying to say. By component I mean the class that is bind to the component.

Comment: Ok, yes that would work but it is not good to specify styles in js. You can add a class to your css, apply it and add borders based on classes. I hope that you are not getting the color from the server api.